# I need merge 2 multidimensional arrays

Tags: php

Array #1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 261
            [ownerName] => George Dwell
            [Department] => Information Technology
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 262
            [ownerName] => Dave Duken
            [Department] => Product
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 258
            [ownerName] => Ruby Richards
            [Department] => Services
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 263
            [ownerName] => Charles Mavric
            [Department] => Services
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 264
            [ownerName] => Austin Mayer
            [Department] => Sales
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 265
            [ownerName] => Aleo Kirb
            [Department] => Sales
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 267
            [ownerName] => dsrana4 dsrana4
            [Department] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 260
            [ownerName] => Jennifer Jackson
            [Department] => Marketing
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 266
            [ownerName] => Allan Francis
            [Department] => Product
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [ownerName] => George Dwell
            [Department] => Information Technology
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [ownerName] => George Dwell
            [Department] => Information Technology
        )

)
```

Array 2#

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 264
            [total_time] => 0.7
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [total_time] => 1.25
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 261
            [total_time] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 258
            [total_time] => 1.4
        )

)
```

I want new array as same like this..

New Array #

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 261
            [ownerName] => George Dwell
            [Department] => Information Technology
            [total_time] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 262
            [ownerName] => Dave Duken
            [Department] => Product
            [total_time] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 258
            [ownerName] => Ruby Richards
            [Department] => Services
            [total_time] => 1.4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 263
            [ownerName] => Charles Mavric
            [Department] => Services
            [total_time] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 264
            [ownerName] => Austin Mayer
            [Department] => Sales
            [total_time] => 0.7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 265
            [ownerName] => Aleo Kirb
            [Department] => Sales
            [total_time] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 267
            [ownerName] => dsrana4 dsrana4
            [Department] => 
            [total_time] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 260
            [ownerName] => Jennifer Jackson
            [Department] => Marketing
            [total_time] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 266
            [ownerName] => Allan Francis
            [Department] => Product
            [total_time] => 0
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [ownerName] => George Dwell
            [Department] => Information Technology
            [total_time] => 1.25
            [total_time] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [ownerName] => George Dwell
            [Department] => Information Technology
            [total_time] => 0
        )

)
```

How can do this?

Comment: have you tried the `merge` method ? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to merge the array's like this. One suggestion is to create the `$new_array` and key the values by the id of `$array_1`. Then you can loop over `$array_2` and update `$new_array` using the id from the object in `$array_2`.

```php
$new_array = [];

foreach ($array_1 as $item) {
    $new_array[$item['id']] = $item;
}

foreach ($array_2 as $item) {
    // Perhaps first make sure that the key exists if array_2 
    // could have a total_time that will not be in array_1
    $new_array[$item->id]['total_time'] = $item->total_time;
}

// In case you must have your keys starting from 0
// you can uncomment the call to array_values.
// $new_array = array_values($new_array);
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$valuesToMerge = collect($array_2);

array_walk($array_1, function (&$item) {
    $item['total_time'] = optional($valuesToMerge->firstWhere('id', $item['id']))->total_time ?? 0;
});
```

- [`array_walk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)
- [`optional`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional)
- [`firstWhere`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first-where)